# URL поменять ссылки в пагинации htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте! Нужна помощь) сейчас на сайте есть пагинация вот такого вида -

```
https://site.tld/skylights?page=2
```

Нужно привести к нормальному виду ссылку

```
https://site.tld/skylights/page-2
```

и поставить 301 редирект.

Помогите пожалуйста реализовать!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй так.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^skylights/page-(.*)$ /skylights?page=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Вот тут подробнее можно почитать про [RewriteRule для Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Comment: Этот RewriteRule ни когда не сработает.

Comment: https://roto.com.ua/skylights?page=2 так и осталось( не поменялась ссылка

Comment: Ну да.. Напутал как с направлением редиректа так и с regex. Такой вариант должен работать

Comment: Вы мне ничего не отправили)

Comment: Я исправил ответ.